# Arbitrary Column Count SQL Data Set (SQL Server Integration Services [SSIS])

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, dataflow

**Background:**

I'm attempting to iterate a list of .sql files, execute each file, save the result of each query to a specially-named, delimited text file. Right now, I achieve this using a completely standalone C# program. I'm an SSIS novice, but I'm very good at C#. Going forward in the IT department I'll be working for, SSIS is the preferred solution, so plopping it all into a giant script action is (sadly) not the solution.

**Issue:**

Below is a picture of my Control Flow.

[image: Control Flow]

The desired effect is as follows:

1. The Foreach loops through a folder of .sql files.
2. The Load SQL task assigns the contents of the current .sql file to a variable.

   (Both of these steps work)
3. Data Flow task:

   [image: Data Flow]

   1. executes the SQL in the variable AND!
   2. saves the arbitrarily sized result to a variable or file.
4. (Back to Control Flow:) Missing: Save report with a varying delimiter and varying file name.
5. Upload Report executes WinSCP to grab the file and put it in n > 1 assigned location(s).

**Question:**

How do I make the data flow **not care** about the **number of columns**? For instance, Report 1 has **five** columns, Report 2 has **50**, and Report 3 has **25**. All of these things are OK. I don't care how many columns it has, and I really could care less about the metadata in this case.

I can do this with C# by just saying "Here's a DataTable, fill it." SSIS apparently lacks this ability to adapt to the number of columns. Yes? No? Say screw it and just do it with a script object? What's the received wisdom on what to do here?

If this question reveals some fundamental misunderstanding of how SSIS works, feel free to comment on that, too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already know how, script it.  SSIS with arbitrary columns is difficult in 2008.  I don't know about that version.

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon this entire approach - it is not a road for success with SSIS.

SSIS caches dataflow metadata (e.g. columns, datatypes, even datatype precision), and a change in that metadata usually implies a change in the package design.

Instead I would build an SSIS package with 3 Data Flow Tasks or as many as you have variations (one per "Report" / SQL script).  Inside each Data Flow Task would be an OLE DB Source and a Flat File Destination.

The strength of this becomes clear at runtime - SSIS can execute many Data Flow Tasks in parallel (default setting is # cores * 2) and outputs text file data at blinding speed compared to C#.